# Как обратится в ConfigParser к атрибутам по имени?

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

Читаю параметры авторизации из конфига, функция выглядит следующим образом:

```
def stage(env):
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read('../config.ini')
    host = config.get(env, 'host')
    port = config.getint(env, 'port')
    return port, host
...

port = stage('test')[0]
```

Смущает то, что обращаюсь к результату функции по индексу, что выглядит нечитабельно, и высок риск запутаться в элементах списка. Есть какой либо способ обратиться к результату наподобие:

```
port = stage('test').port
```

Каким образом это лучше реализовать?

Comment: ["Что делать с ответами на вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [этим решением](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8578508/5741205):

```
In [19]: config = ConfigParser()

In [20]: config.read(r'C:\Temp\test.ini')
Out[20]: ['C:\\Temp\\test.ini']

In [21]: cfg = dict(config.items('test'))

In [22]: cfg
Out[22]: {'host': 'host1', 'port': '1111'}

In [23]: cfg.get('host')
Out[23]: 'host1'

In [24]: cfg.get('port')
Out[24]: '1111'
```

Тестовый файл:

```
[test]
host = host1
port = 1111
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел более изящный способ - через именованные кортежи:

```
def stage(env):
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(path)
    host = config.get(env, 'host')
    port = config.get(env, 'port')
    tpl = namedtuple('config', ['host', 'port'])
    res = tpl(host, port)
    return res

tst = stage('test')
print(tst.host)
```

Comment: интересно чем этот способ более изящный?

Comment: тем, что к нужному атрибуту можно обратиться напрямую, как и требовалось изначально, а не использовать для этого методы словаря. 
как бонус, при этом именованный кортеж не удастся случайно переопределить.